# Minecraft command unfindable unbalanced brackets

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that there been about three others persons that asked something like this, but the command is not so long:

> /summon Skeleton ~ ~1 ~ {ActiveEffect:[{minecraft:speed,Amplifier:10,Duration:3600},{minecraft:health_boost,Amplifier:7,Duration:3600},{minecraft:jump_boost,Amplifier:7,Duration:3600},{minecraft:resistance,Amplifier:7,Duration:3600},{minecraft:strength,Amplifier:7,Duration:3600},{minecraft:glowing,Duration:3600}],HandItems:[{id:iron_sword},{id:shield}],ArmorItems:[{leather_helmet}],CustomName:Warrior,Visible:5,Equipment:[{id:397,Count:1},{CustomName:Warrior’s Head}], DropChances:[1.0f]}

Without the tag, it make:

> {[{},{},{},{},{},{}],[{},{}],[{}],,[{},{}],[]}

I checked and re-checked, but I just can't find where is the error.
Here is what the command block says:

[image]

Comment: A little bit of double checking would find the issue, I bet. You have a semicolon instead of a comma, I think. Not sure, though, because I don't play Minecraft.

Comment: Yes this is right; in fact, I followed the way to check the command's brackets with the already-have-an answer question but I still don't find it. If it's interest you, I've edited the question.

Comment: Except now you've fixed it. If you had done that prior to asking, you would have found the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking it down into a method-by-method format shows the issue:

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~1 ~
{
    ActiveEffect:
    [{
        minecraft:speed,Amplifier:10,Duration:3600
    },
    {
        minecraft:health_boost,Amplifier:7,Duration:3600
    },
    {
        minecraft:jump_boost,Amplifier:7,Duration:3600
    };        <--- Here is your typo
    {
        minecraft:resistance,Amplifier:7,Duration:3600
    },
    {
        minecraft:strength,Amplifier:7,Duration:3600
    },
    {
        minecraft:glowing,Duration:3600
    }],
    HandItems:
    [{
        id:iron_sword
    },
    {
        id:shield
    }],
    ArmorItems:
    [{
        leather_helmet
    }],
    CustomName:Warrior,Visible:5,Equipment:
    [{
        id:397,Count:1
    },
    {
        CustomName:Warrior’s Head
    }],
    DropChances:[1.0f]
}
```

By breaking it down, you can see you have used a `;` about halfway through your `ActiveEffect` block. This is likely what's throwing out your command, as in *most* programming languages, this is used to terminate the line.

In this command however, as from your screenshot, the error is suggesting a parsing fail - caused by an unexpected character: the `;`.

**EDIT:** while this isn't actually causing the error, (Courtesy of Kcats) you are missing the syntax for the declaration of the leather helmet - it should be `id:leather_helmet`

Comment: The problem is probably not that the semicolon "ends the line", and rather that they simply have a semicolon where there's supposed to be a comma, which can cause any kind of parsing error.

Comment: also id: is missing for leather_helmet

Comment: Thank you very much, but the command don't seem to work as well as it is: the skeleton acts very weird...

Comment: @Kimatuy I don't believe that the command has anything to do with the AI of the skeleton, the only thing you have changed is the speed and the jump height. If it's doing anything other than that, I can't see how the command you have used would be affecting it's behaviour